# QGIS Points are not retaining original attributes

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, map-point

I am trying to map birth and death locations for several hundred people in the US and Europe (for a total of 532 points in one layer). Twice now I have discovered that somewhere during this process (of manually going to each location and placing a point and filling in the attribute table) the original attribute information has been switched. For example, attributes given to a point in England are now associated with a point in North Carolina. I don't understand why this is happening. Why would attribute information move around like that? It makes no sense. Please help. I've been working on this for months. I just might lose my mind if I have to do this all over again.

Comment: can you let us know how you're doing the original 'mapping' of the birth and death locations? What is your source data format? Are you geocoding from an address or plotting an XY? Details like this might help out...

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE! Along with what @mapBaker mentioned, also make sure the CRS (Coordinate Reference System) for both your layers **and** your project are the same. You can set them by right-clicking on the layer and selecting _Set Layer CRS_ and _Set Project CRS from Layer_.

Comment: mapBaker, I am not geocoding or plotting an XY. I am actually going to the location on the map and placing the point by using the add feature button.  Joseph, I'm very new to using QGIS, so I did what you suggested but since the attributes are already switched I don't see how it will help. i just added a test point, and just after saving my edits it has already switched the attributes.

Comment: Do you have "on the fly reprojection" selected? Can you tell us exactly where you placed the point, and where it "switched to"? What are the attribute columns called?